# Not getting the output as expected in Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

i know multithreading a bit but not in vast and i think the problem is of multithreading. I am calling a method to set label's text by invoking a new thread and leaving it blank after a specified time. I am getting the desired output every time but not only the place which i am going to show you by my piece of code. I am expecting that message should be set and disappeared after the specified time and the window should be minimized after that time. But what actually happening is when it is going to the other thread main thread execution starts and goes for sleep for 5 sec and the message is not appearing and after 5 sec window is getting minimized without showing the message which i am setting on the label.

(Main thread)

```
Validation.setMessageOnLabel("Username and password has been copied", jLabel15,1.5F);
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PasswordManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
setState(ICONIFIED);
```

**validation.java (setMessageOnLabel())**

```
static public void setMessageOnLabel(final String msg, final JLabel label, final float time)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            label.setText(msg);

            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (time*1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PasswordManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            label.setText("");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Swing is not thread safe and this is a direct violation of Swing's threading policy. All interactions with GUI components must be done on the EDT. Your first code snippet is also sleeping the EDT for five seconds, blocking the GUI. In short [read all of this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Thread.sleep(5000);`, that block `EDT`.

For that purposes you can use swing `Timer`, examine next example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel lbl;

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        lbl = new JLabel(" ");
        JButton setText = new JButton("setText");
        setText.addActionListener(getActionListener());
        add(lbl);
        add(setText,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private ActionListener getActionListener() {
        return new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                lbl.setText("wait...");
                Timer t = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        lbl.setText("");
                        setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
                    }
                });
                t.setRepeats(false);
                t.start();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: Wonderful of you to talk of `Event Dispatcher Thread` but seems like your main method is missing one(in simpler words, you yourself never cared to start the GUI on the EDT in the first place, by wrapping contents of main method inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`). Moreover, please for future post, always try to use `BorderLayout.PAGE_END` instead of `BorderLayout.SOUTH` since Java is encouraging it's use since `JDK 1.4`

Comment: @nIcEcOw *"..since Java is encouraging it's use since `JDK 1.4`"*  ..and you are also encouraging, and me (though not since 1.4, since you only alerted me to it later).  Keep up the good work. :)

Comment: thanks i got it i cant vote it up because it requires 15 point to do it. Thanks a lot i got it.

Comment: @nIcEcOw You are right when I run from main it isn't EDT, but for simple example it can be done. ALso, can you put some links about difference of `BorderLayout.SOUTH` and `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`.

Comment: @alex2410: Actually, everythingy can be done without EDT, though the result will not be predictable, in those cases. My simple point is, if one is not bothered about EDT in the first place, what's the need to care about it later on. And about the difference, there is no difference, just Java came out with these new fields to represent the same thingy, as mentioned just below the first __Launch Button__, in this [Java Docs related to BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) And please do read that __Version Note__

Comment: @nIcEcOw, I know about unpredictable behavior in that case, but from main you cant catch that behavior. Really, i always use `GridBagLayout` because of it I used `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, for the future try to replace it with `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`.

Comment: @alex2410: If you will go by what [Java Docs for GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) says, again you need to change this thingy in that part too, since JDK 1.4 Java introduced these in every area of their use, whether `BorderLayout` or `GridBagLayout` everywhere :-) Do watch under __Specifying Constraints__'s __anchor__ property, you will know this thingy too :-)

Answer (score 4):

Since you're calling `setState()` directly, I assume the first code snippet is part of a `JFrame`. In that case you're most probably sending the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) to sleep for 5 seconds and thus prevent screen updates during that time.

Put the sleep into another thread or use a swing worker instead and call `setState()` on the EDT in the worker's callback method, since `setState()` is not labelled as thread-safe and calling it on a thread other than the EDT might result in unexpected behavior.

From the linked tutorial:

> Some Swing component methods are labelled "thread safe" in the API specification; these can be safely invoked from any thread. **All other Swing component methods must be invoked from the event dispatch thread.**  Programs that ignore this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to unpredictable errors that are difficult to reproduce.

Comment: thanks i got it i cant vote it up because it requires 15 point to do it. Thanks a lot i got it.

Comment: @tarunverma you could at least accept the answer if it really helped you in order to improve your accept ratio and to help others who visit this thread.

Answer (score -2):

When dealing with Swing components you shuld not use threads like that. Launch your own SwingWorker instead.

```
public class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public Object doInBackground() {
        //your code here
        //dont forget to repaint changed component or validate parent of it, 
        //if your text dont shows up.
        return null;
    }
}
```

you can also execute your own runnable via SwingUtilites

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //again your code here...
        }
    });
```

Comment: You certainly must not do any of those things from the `doInBackground` method. Swing is not threadsafe and repainting or validating from a worker thread will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Swing is not threadsafe, i agree on that, but SwingWorker and SwingUtilities dont mess up with EDT. They are design, for interact with Swing components. Using swingworker to load data and update progres bar of this operation is a book example.

Comment: Nope. Swingworker has `publish` and `process` methods for interacting with the EDT during the running of a background process. You cannot interact with the GUI from the worker thread. You may want to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html).

Comment: Hmm, you're right, i checked my old codes. Never called validation methods they are not marked as thread safe.Hovever Swing worker could be still used for that.